# Log4J2 with Routing Appenders and ThreadContext

Tags: java, log4j2

I have some issues with log4j2 and the routing appenders.

My application generates different threads and within each thread I do something like this

`ThreadContext.put("threadName", processName);`

and **processName** will be generated within the thread based on different information. But that is not important, the only important information is, that **processName** will be different in each thread.

Now I have this **log4j2.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="${ctx:threadName}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:threadName}"
                                 fileName="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log"
                                 filePattern="../log/${ctx:threadName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                                 createOnDemand="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="de.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And log4j creates logfiles for each thread without any issues.

Unfortunately log4j will create a logfile called **${ctx:threadName}.log**. In this logfile the log messages from JSCH will appear. I guess that JSCH will create its own thread and since JSCH won't put a ThredName into the ThreadContext, log4j can not replace the variable and uses the variable from the configuration as the logfile name.

My goal would be to write all logfiles **without** a threadName in the ThreadContext into a single logfile.

I found this link in the documentation from log4j

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/faq.html#separate_log_files

but the issue is, that in that example they know what the value of threadName is. In my case I don't know the value.

ChatGPT told me, that I have to change the **pattern** within the  element and use a double $ like this

`<Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">`

and than I can add a second  element like this

```
<Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
                <Route key="$${ctx:threadName}">
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:threadName}"
                                 fileName="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log"
                                 filePattern="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
                                 createOnDemand="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>            
                <Route key="null">
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-service" 
                                fileName="../log/default-service.log" 
                                filePattern="../log/default-service.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" 
                                createOnDemand="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>            

            </Routes>
        </Routing>
```

But this is not working - I guess log4j interprets **null** as a String. The second approach was to remove the key attribute from the **fallback route** like this

```
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
                <Route key="$${ctx:threadName}">
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:threadName}"
                                 fileName="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log"
                                 filePattern="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
                                 createOnDemand="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-service"
                                fileName="../log/default-service.log"
                                filePattern="../log/default-service.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
                                createOnDemand="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%-40.-40c{1}] %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>

            </Routes>
```

But in this case all  log messages will be stored in the default-service.log.

Does anyone has a good idea what to do in this case?

Many greetings and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing appender is tricky, because everything **except** the contents of `<Route>` is interpolated at compile-time, while the contents of `<Route>` will be evaluated if that route is chosen. Therefore if you have:

```xml
<Routing name="RoutingAppender">
  <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
    <Route key="$${ctx:threadName}">
      <!-- Content 1 -->
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <!-- Content 2 -->
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Routing>
```

it will be interpolated at configuration time to obtain:

```xml
<Routing name="RoutingAppender">
  <Routes pattern="${ctx:threadName}">
    <Route key="${ctx:threadName}">
      <!-- Content 1 unchanged -->
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <!-- Content 2 unchanged -->
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Routing>
```

At runtime the pattern `${ctx:threadName}` will be interpolated and matched against **non-interpolated** keys. Therefore:

- if `ThreadContext.get("threadName")` is `null`, the expression `${ctx:threadName}` will evaluate to itself `${ctx:threadName}` and match the key of the **first** (not second) route,
- if `ThreadContext.get("threadName")` is **not** `null`, it will not match any key and the **second** (default) route will be chosen.

### Solutions

You can:

- either replace the contents of the second route with the fist one (in your last attempts) and viceversa,
- or add a default value for `${ctx:threadName}` and use just a single default route:

```xml
<Properties>
  <Property name="threadName" value="default-service"/>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
  <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
    <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
      <Route>
        <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:threadName}"
                     fileName="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log"
                     filePattern="../log/${ctx:threadName}.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
                     createOnDemand="true">
        ...
        </RollingFile>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </Routing>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thank you for your help. I will try your solutions tonight but that sounds promissing

Comment: Thank you - it works - I didn't noticed the double $$ at the pattern attribute.